# How to get grayscale value of pixels from grayscale image in xCode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I was wondering how to determine the equivalent of RGB values for a grayscale image. The original image is grayscale and everything I have found online is converting an RGB image pixel values to the grayscale pixel values. I already can read in the image. Ideally, this would be for xCode.

I was wondering if there was a class which would do this for me. If so, and you could point me to it, that would be great. I will read on it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

NOTE: I am a beginner in C++ and do not have time to learn everything formally; I have to learn all of my programming on the fly.

Comment: Please: it's Xcode… not xCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more information to transform from a simple Greyscale to RGB, when you do reverse operation, the color information is "lost", as the three channels are set to same value(depending on the algorithm each channel will have a different/same weight in the final color computation).

Digital cameras, usually store more information per pixel, 12 bits per channel in 35mm and 14 bits per channel in medium format (those bits number are the average, some products offer less or even more quality).

Thanks to those additional bits per channel, the camera can compute the "real" color, or what it thinks is the real color based on some parameters.

TL;DR: You can't without more data from your source, in this case the image.

Comment: I am going from grayscale (original image) to grayscale (file), and then attempting to figure out the intensity of all the pictures in the image.

Comment: So, ok, you have your data in one file, as is grayscale that should represent the actual intensity of the pixels. what do you need help with? reading the file in c++?. What is the file format?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a gray value to RGB by setting each component of the RGB value to the gray value:

```
ColorRGB myColorRGB = ColorRGBMake(myGrayValue, myGrayValue, myGrayValue);
```

Comment: How do you get the gray value from a grayscale image? @geowar